# Pass ngTable row input data to ngDialog input

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ngtable

I'm trying to pass a model to ngDialog Template

Editable Table

```
<table ng-table="tableParams" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="release in releases track by $index">
           <td style="width:5%" data-title="'Version'" ng-model="release.version">{{release.version}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This is the button that opens the Dialog box and calls $scope.edit

```
<button ng-click="edit(release)" title="Edit" class="btn btn-sm btn-default">
```

This is the HTML for the ngDialog template

```
        <script type="text/ng-template" id="editRelease">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <input type="text" ng-model="release.version" class="form-control" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </script>
```

This is my controller in Which I am trying to populate a row

```
$scope.edit = function (release) {
    ngDialog.openConfirm({
        template: 'editRelease',
        className: 'ngdialog-theme-default',
        scope: $scope,
        controller: ['$scope', function ($scope) {
            $scope.$watch('release', function (passedObject) {
                console.log(release.version);
            });
        }]
    })
};
```

I have managed to pass the object from the model and log it into the console. How can I populate the dialog box with the text from my table into the dialog box when the edit button is pressed?

Answer (score 1):

you need to use **resolve** to pass data to modal :

```
 ngDialog.openConfirm({
    template: 'editRelease',
    className: 'ngdialog-theme-default',
    scope: $scope,
    controller: ['$scope','release', function ($scope,release) {
        $scope.$watch('release', function (passedObject) {
            console.log(release.version);
        });
    }],
    resolve: {
        release: function () {
            return release;
        }
    }
})
```

source : https://github.com/likeastore/ngDialog#resolve-objectstring-function